# how to get cfhttp.filecontent when throwonerror=true on cfhttp?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfhttp

I make a REST service call using `cfhttp` with the `throwonerror` attribute set to true.
When I use a try/catch statement to capture the error, I can't seem to find a way to output what error the REST service call tried to return, which would reside in the `cfhttp.filecontent` variable.

I also tried putting the result in a variable. Coldfusion keeps telling me that cfhttp and that variable dont exist. It seems like the call and its result get thrown out the door when an exception is raised.

I've read some advice on setting `throwonerror=false` and capturing the statuscodes myself, but that seems like silly work. Anyody have any thoughts on this?

```
<cftry>
    <cfhttp url="#restUrl##arguments.method#/#arguments.params#" charset="utf-8" throwonerror="true" result="haha" />
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#haha#" />
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" abort />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

**UPDATE:**
I've submited a bug report to Adobe, as Adamn suggested: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=newBug. I can confirm it works in Railo, but doesn't work on CF10. Adam could also confirm it doesn't work on CF11.

Comment: I think the theory behind throwonerror=false is that the the CF code is successful even if the called page returns a 500 error.  You can inspect the haha.statusCode to see what happened and handle accordingly.

Comment: I realise that the throwonerror can be set to false and that I can check on statuscode. But I feel more secure when CF does my errorhandling as oppose to me checking on statuscodes myself and then throwing an error manually.
I really don't see why the throwonerror attribute would not pass the cfhttp result body to the error struct somewhere.

Comment: CFHTTP can be used to access your code or someone else's code.  If you treat both scenarios as an external call for the purposes of encapsulation, then the CFHTTP call, unless there is an error in the calling tag is going to be unbroken code even if the called page is broken.  If the external page is in error, then you throw your error and trap and log etc there.  If you are calling a broken service, your code isn't broken and you inspect results and handle accordingly.  For me it is really a separation of concerns issue.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in CF (I tested on CF10 & 11). On Railo, the response is still returned from `<cfhttp>`. Pls raise a bug: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm

Comment: @AdamCameron: thanks. I can confirm it doesn't work on CF10, but it works on Railo. I've submitted a bug and updated my original post.