# How to try-catch CFHTTP error?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to catch a REST service call via CFHTTP with the throwonerror set to true, but in my catch-output, it's not showing anything.

```
<cftry> 
    <cfhttp url="https://app.knowledg.com/api/head/article1.json" method="get" timeout="15" throwonerror="true" >       
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="_authbykey" value="56a7d8c123131c4058361687"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="project_id" value="55c4ffd12331c527e294fe6"> 
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="replaceSnippets" value="true" />
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="limit" value="99" />
         <cfhttpparam type="url" name="url_hash" value="#URL.title#" />    
    </cfhttp>
    <cfcatch type="any" >
        <cfoutput>
        Error: #cfcatch.message#
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

However, this is the error on the page. I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719926/how-to-get-cfhttp-filecontent-when-throwonerror-true-on-cfhttp) that mentioned similar issues but that thread was a year ago and did not receive any answer.

Error in custom script module
(/mysite/customcf/knowledge/articleDetail.cfm)
Object of type class java.lang.String cannot be used as an array

Comment: what line is that error being thrown on? If `cfcatch.message` is an array you can't output it like you are. You need to use `<cfdump>`

Comment: The error is throwing on this line: <cfhttp url="https://app.knowledg.com/api/head/article1.json" method="get" timeout="15" throwonerror="true" >

Comment: I tried the cfdump and it's not showing anything either.

Comment: The <cfoutput> did not even seemed to work because I just put some text in the cfoutput tag and it's not out putting that either.

Comment: Is that the exact code? Under CF11 it hits the catch clause and a `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">` shows a Connection Failure: Status code unavailable under CF11.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with a compiler exception, not a run time exception that can be caught with a cftry/cfcatch block.

[Handling compiler exceptions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d1b.html)

> You cannot handle compiler exceptions directly on the page where they occur, because the exception is caught before ColdFusion starts running the page code. Fix all compiler exceptions as part of the development process. Use the reported error message and the code debugging techniques discussed in Debugging and Troubleshooting Applications to identify and correct the cause of the error.

You need to debug the `/mysite/customcf/knowledge/articleDetail.cfm` file before attempting to make an http call to it.

Comment: I intentionally put a 1 in the aritlce.json file to simulate some errors and the try-catch could not handle this error. I am trying to put some friendly error messages to the page in cases where third-party REST services may have issues.